# How share selected text in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, select, text, share

I work on reading book app in flutter, i make the text selectable text, but the problem when i want share the selected text, thier is any way to do it ?

I try use onselectionchanged in selectable to capture the selected text but this not work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `SelectableText(contextMenuBuilder: (context, editableTextState) {
final TextEditingValue value = editableTextState.textEditingValue;
final textSeleted = value.selection.textInside(value.text);
final List<ContextMenuButtonItem> buttonItems = editableTextState.contextMenuButtonItems;
buttonItems.insert(0, ContextMenuButtonItem(label: 'share',onPressed: () {print("done"); ContextMenuController.removeAny();}, ));
return AdaptiveTextSelectionToolbar.buttonItems(
anchors: editableTextState.contextMenuAnchors,
buttonItems: buttonItems, ); },
"${currentSection.content}",)`

Comment: this my code after implement the solution of **Franklin Diaz**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onselectionchanged should work for you, although it is executed every time the user changes the selection, which I don't think is what you want, the normal thing is to add a button to the context menu with the one you want to share in your case.

use contextMenuBuilder,
note: this example use url_launcher for send sms with the text, you need run

> flutter pub add url_launcher

example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Material App Bar'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: SelectableText(
            contextMenuBuilder: (context, editableTextState) {
              final TextEditingValue value = editableTextState.textEditingValue;

              // Get text selected
              final textSeleted = value.selection.textInside(value.text);

              // Get button default of text selection
              final List<ContextMenuButtonItem> buttonItems =
                  editableTextState.contextMenuButtonItems;

              // Add new button share
              buttonItems.insert(
                  0,
                  ContextMenuButtonItem(
                    label: 'share',
                    onPressed: () {
                      final Uri smsLaunchUri = Uri(
                        scheme: 'sms',
                        path: '011122355',
                        queryParameters: <String, String>{
                          'body': textSeleted,
                        },
                      );

                      // Launch sms with text selected
                      launchUrl(smsLaunchUri);

                      // Close context menu
                      ContextMenuController.removeAny();
                    },
                  ));

              return AdaptiveTextSelectionToolbar.buttonItems(
                anchors: editableTextState.contextMenuAnchors,
                buttonItems: buttonItems,
              );
            },
            'Hello World text bla bla 123',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks bro, your answer is very helpful, but that is crazy, I implement this on my code  and is work just two time after that the code not work,

Comment: `SelectableText(contextMenuBuilder: (context, editableTextState) {
final TextEditingValue value = editableTextState.textEditingValue;
final textSeleted = value.selection.textInside(value.text);
final List<ContextMenuButtonItem> buttonItems = editableTextState.contextMenuButtonItems;
buttonItems.insert(0, ContextMenuButtonItem(label: 'share',onPressed: () {print("done"); ContextMenuController.removeAny();}, ));
return AdaptiveTextSelectionToolbar.buttonItems(
anchors: editableTextState.contextMenuAnchors,
buttonItems: buttonItems, ); },
"${currentSection.content}",)` my code after you S

Comment: when I implement your code on new page is work, but on my code is not work

Comment: instead of using "${currentSection.content}" use textSeleted. and put your code inside onPressed: () {"you code here"} just below the print("done");

Comment: thanks for your time, but I don't think this is work, look at the code i post it below, if you can tell me your opinion about it

Comment: thank you bro, finally now I solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

```
SelectableText(
        contextMenuBuilder: (context, editableTextState) {
            final TextEditingValue value = editableTextState.textEditingValue;
                      
                                    // Get text selected
                                    final textSeleted = value.selection.textInside(value.text);
                      
                                    // Get button default of text selection
                                    final List<ContextMenuButtonItem> buttonItems =
                                        editableTextState.contextMenuButtonItems;
                      
                                    // Add new button share
                                    buttonItems.insert(
                                        0,
                                        ContextMenuButtonItem(
                                          label: 'share',
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            // final Uri smsLaunchUri = Uri(
                                            //   scheme: 'sms',
                                            //   path: '07730303670',
                                            //   queryParameters: <String, String>{
                                            //     'body': textSeleted,
                                            //   },
                                            // );
                      
                                            // // Launch sms with text selected
                                            // launchUrl(smsLaunchUri);
                      
                                            // // Close context menu
                                            print("done");
                                            ContextMenuController.removeAny();
                                          },
                                        ));
                      
                                    return AdaptiveTextSelectionToolbar.buttonItems(
                                      anchors: editableTextState.contextMenuAnchors,
                                      buttonItems: buttonItems,
                                    );
                                  },
                                  "${currentSection.content}",
                                )
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**